# Led head light - preventing Battery contacts from rusting

Tags: battery-operated

I have a cheapo Asda headlight who'sbattery contacts keep rusting over. Even if you leave the bloody thing indoors it rusts after awhile. Is there any chemicals I can put on it to stop this from happening?

Comment: The stuff is called *Terminal Grease*

Comment: I've used silicone grease and vacuum grease (high end silicone grease) with good results.

Comment: Gold-plate them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Dielectric Grease is used to keep moisture out and help maintain seals. Commonly used for car light connectors. Same can be used for your battery connectors.